# Backbone Collection is Half-Sorted When Comparator is Used

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, backbone-model

I am using backbone's collection model to display a sorted list of strings on a backbone view.  Here is the model and the comparator:

```js
var MenuItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  comparator: function (a, b) {
    if (a.get('name') < b.get('name')) {
      return 1;
    } else if (b.get('name') > a.get('name')) {
      return -1;
    }
  },

  model: MenuItem,
  url: '/items'
});
```

When the code is run, only the first six of the twelve items in the list are sorted, the rest remains unsorted.  When `comparator: 'name'` is used the list is fully sorted, but when a function is used, this problem occurs.

Anyone know why this might be happening?  Could this be a Backbone bug?  I am using Backbone 1.1.0

Comment: Could you post the names items that are being sorted?

Comment: [""sort" comparator functions take two models, and return -1 if the first model should come before the second, 0 if they are of the same rank and 1 if the first model should come after."](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator). You're missing one of those three cases so all bets are off.

Comment: @Divey: {Chili con carne,Cheeseburger,Pizza,Caesar salad,Garden salad,Brownie,Carrots,Cheesecake,Green beans,Mashed potatoes,Spaghetti and meatballs,Tomato salad} is being sorted as {Carrots,Tomato salad,Spaghetti and meatballs,Pizza,Mashed potatoes,Green beans,Garden salad,Chili con carne,Cheesecake,Cheeseburger,Caesar salad,Brownie}

Comment: @mu is too short: adding `else {return 0;}` makes no difference wse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working code.

```
var MenuItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: function (a, b) {
        if (a.get('name') < b.get('name')) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a.get('name') > b.get('name')) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is jsfiddle with output so you can compare http://jsfiddle.net/ek44Z/2/

The main problem was with function content. You need return `-1` in `if` statement and compare `a` and `b` in `else if` and return `1`. Basically your `else if` have never been called.

Have a good coding.